# How to get user's permission on SharePoint site with REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, rest

I want to know user's permission on SharePoint site with REST API. Could anyone please help me to generate the REST query which will give me user's permission on the site. I don't want to know permission of the current user. My module contains people picker field in which I will take input from username ( a user whose permission is to be check) and in other text box user will enter url or name of the site. So I want to check the permission of entered user on entered site. 
Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot check directly, alternate is to use effectiveBasePermissions for diffrent masks.

```
function checkPermissions() {
    var call = jQuery.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +
            "/_api/Web/effectiveBasePermissions",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });

    call.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var manageListsPerms = new SP.BasePermissions();
        manageListsPerms.initPropertiesFromJson(data.d.EffectiveBasePermissions);

        var manageLists = manageListsPerms.has(SP.PermissionKind.manageLists);

        var message = jQuery("#message");
        message.text("Manage Lists: " + manageLists);
    });
}
```

[Ref link](http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/checking-user-permissions-from-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/)