# How to check logged in user has access to a another SharePoint site or not using REST Api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am developing a web part, where I need to check logged in user does have access to few SharePoint sites(SiteA, SiteB, SiteC) or not. I am following currently below approach. I am passing each site url to a function(hasAccess) and returning true or false.

It is giving correct result if logged in user has full control permission to that site. But if the user has read or view permission then still it is giving access denied to that site.

If someone could help to achieve my requirement with correct approach, it would be very helpful.

```
export async function hasAccess(url: string): Promise<boolean> {
   try {
      const webUrl = `${url}/_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,RoleDefinitionBindings`
      const response = await fetch(webUrl, {
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: { 
           accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
  });
  if (!response.ok) {
     throw new Error('unathorized');
  }
  return true;
 } catch (e) {
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`_api/Web/RoleAssignments?$expand=Member,RoleDefinitionBindings` requires extra permissions. You may take advantage of below endpoint to check the user's permission on a site:

- /_api/web/getusereffectivepermissions

More references:

- [How to get user's permission on SharePoint site with REST API?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199409/how-to-get-users-permission-on-sharepoint-site-with-rest-api)
- https://joemcshea.intellipointsolutions.com/determining-the-permissions-of-the-current-user-with-rest/

BR

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using Search API. Please refer to this question ([REST API Prompting for user credentials](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/276317/rest-api-prompting-for-user-credentials)) hope it helps